# custom permalinks for category archive ( custom base and no parent slug )

Tags: categories, permalinks

For the default taxonomy i.e category  , I want custom permalinks  with

```
i) base = "post/c"  and 
ii) without any parent slug
```

For eg: if I have categories

```
cat-a
   subcat-a1
   subcat-a2
cat-b
   subcat-a2
   subcat-a2
```

so I want permalinks like

example.com/post/c/cat-a
example.com/post/c/subcat-a1
example.com/post/c/subcat-a2
example.com/post/c/cat-b
example.com/post/c/subcat-b1
example.com/post/c/subcat-b2

I am using the following code .. I solves the issue (ii) but not issue (i) i.e base 'post/c'

```
add_filter('term_link', 'ojasya_no_term_parents', 1000, 3);
function ojasya_no_term_parents($url, $term, $taxonomy) {
if($taxonomy == 'category'){
$term_nicename = $term->slug;
$url = trailingslashit(get_option( 'home' )) . user_trailingslashit( $term_nicename, 'category' );
}
return $url;
}
// Add our custom post cat rewrite rules
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array', 'ojasya_no_category_parents_rewrite_rules');
function ojasya_no_category_parents_rewrite_rules($rules) {
$new_rules = array();
$terms = get_terms( array(
'taxonomy' => 'category',
'post_type' => 'post',
'hide_empty' => false,
));
if($terms && !is_wp_error($terms)){
foreach ($terms as $term){
$term_slug = $term->slug;
$new_rules[$term_slug.'/?$'] = 'index.php?category='.$term_slug;
$new_rules[$term_slug.'/page/([0-9]{1,})/?$'] = 'index.php?category='.$term_slug.'&paged=$matches[1]';
$new_rules[$term_slug.'/(?:feed/)?(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$'] = 'index.php?category='.$term_slug.'&feed=$matches[1]';
}
}
return $new_rules + $rules;
}
```

Please help me out on this . Thanks in advance

Comment: What it is I am missing? If you have permalinks set to `%post_name%` and you have changed the category base to what you desire. What you want should be working without editing the changes you describe?

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do to achieve this is to modify the `category` taxonomy arguments by using `register_taxonomy()` again at the `init` hook after the `category` taxonomy has been registered. This can be done with any taxonomy as in the following snippet.

**Code for Taxonomies in General (Code for this use case below):**

```
function mytheme_change_category_args() {

    // Get the taxonomy.
    $category = get_taxonomy( 'category' );

    // change the rewrite slug on the taxonomy itself.
    // Note that if your permalink structure is currently 
    // "/post/%postname%", this should be changed to "c", and 
    // "with_front" should be set to "true".
    $category->rewrite['slug'] = 'post/c'; 

    // do not use the text that comes before the first 
    // rewrite tag (%...%) in the permalink settings, unless the
    // setting is "/post/%postname%" as explained above. 
    $category->rewrite['with_front'] = false; 

    // Keep the category hierarchical, but make the permalinks flat.
    $category->rewrite['hierarchical'] = false;

    // register_taxonomy() is used to create OR modify a taxonomy. 
    // make sure the taxonomy object is cast to an array.
    register_taxonomy( 'category', 'post', (array) $category ); 

}

// Make sure this happens after the original tax is init. Priority 10 is fine.
add_action( 'init', 'mytheme_change_category_args', 10 );
```

**Note:**

Go to `Settings->Permalinks`and hit "Save Changes" to flush the rewrite rules. No need to filter term links, add rewrite rules, or anything else.

---

**To answer your question specifically:**

In order to do this with the core WP taxonomies like `category` and `post_tag`, we have to keep in mind the Category and Tag permalink settings at `Settings->Permalinks` Which the above example does not. The best way to do this is actually the simplest way too.

**Code for this use case:**

**Option 1:**

```
function mytheme_change_category_args() {

    $category = get_taxonomy( 'category' );
    $post_tag = get_taxonomy( 'post_tag' );

    $category->rewrite['hierarchical'] = false;
    $category->rewrite['with_front'] = false;
    $post_tag->rewrite['with_front'] = false;

    register_taxonomy( 'category', 'post', (array) $category ); 
    register_taxonomy( 'post_tag', 'post', (array) $post_tag ); 

}

add_action( 'init', 'mytheme_change_category_args', 50 );
```

All you have to do is set `category` to non-hierarchical permalinks, and set `with_front` to false on both `category` and `post_tag`. then set your permalinks at `Settings->Permalinks` as in the image below **;)**

[image: Cat Tag Permalinks]

**Option 2:**

```
function mytheme_change_category_args() {

    $category = get_taxonomy( 'category' );
    $post_tag = get_taxonomy( 'post_tag' );

    $category->rewrite['hierarchical'] = false;
    $category->rewrite['with_front'] = true;
    $post_tag->rewrite['with_front'] = true;

    register_taxonomy( 'category', 'post', (array) $category ); 
    register_taxonomy( 'post_tag', 'post', (array) $post_tag ); 

}

add_action( 'init', 'mytheme_change_category_args', 50 );
```

In this case, what you have to do is set `category` to non-hierarchical permalinks (as in Option 1), and set `with_front` to true on both `category` and `post_tag`. Then, set your permalinks at `Settings->Permalinks` as in the image below, keeping in mind that any plain text tags that you place before the first rewrite tag (`%...%`) of the POST PERMALINK setting will appear before the cat/tag permalink base. **If this is set to `/post/%...%/%...%/%...%/`, this is the best option, for sure.**

[image: Permalink Settings Screen Shot]

Comment: @terminator I just tested this to be sure. This is what you want right here (see second example).

Answer (score -2):

if you will add post id in url anywhere then it will easy otherwise your post title must be unique. So get whole post by title and use `add_rewrite_rule` function.

Comment: It's not really very helpful to say "add_rewrite rule" - what rewrite rule would you propose. In my limited experience, this question, (which is becoming popular) just can't be done. Though I would be excited to see someone's successful answer.

Comment: i already told add_rewrite rule. With help of this you can make any type of url in wordpress.

Comment: I look forward to the forthcoming update to your answer where you demonstrate the detailed rewrite rule that you would recommend to enable the questioner to successfully achieve their goal.

Comment: here is docs: https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule  . I already wasted 1 week in wp custom links. Only it works well and it is also official.